# How to read existing excel file with xlsio and flutter

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, desktop-application

To create an excel file in **xlsio** (in Flutter) [See docs](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio#create-a-simple-excel-document) the following code is needed:

```
// Create a new Excel document.
final Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
```

But how do I find an existing excel file (I am building a desktop app) in a given directory and work with that in **xlsio**?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to read excel files with xlsio. What about the [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel) package?

Comment: @TripleNine I thought about that, adding both excel and xlsio (since xlsio is more convinient in handling these kind of stuff, and also excel's *Pub Points* is kind of worrying me) to my bundle. But is it optimal for the repo health to add both packages?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no easy way to read an existing excel file. So I just used the *[excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel)* package to read the files. (Suggessted by [@TripleNine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16463801/triplenine))